# Firebase Storage Rules customMetadata not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I made some rules to access shared files only for a group of people in Firebase Storage.

The way I do this is to put all the uid's in the customMetadata as keys

```
[uid: Value]
```

When I evaluate if the user can read and write the data, I do this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
     match /{accountId}/{allPaths=**} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid in request.resource.metadata.keys() && request.auth != null;
        allow read: if request.auth.uid in request.metadata.keys();
  }
 }
}
```

I can write successfully, but I just can't read the data.

I have tried all kind of ways:

```
request.metadata[request.auth.uid] == 'theValue'
request.resource.metadata[request.auth.uid] == 'theValue
request.auth.uid in request.metadata
request.auth.uid in request.resource.metadata.keys()
```

Nothing works.

Comment: Can you try `allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.metadata.keys();` ?

Comment: Omg you are right. It works now... I was so sure that I had tried that also  But thanks!

Comment: Great! I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.metadata.keys();
```

I see that you've tried `request.resource` many times. This variable is only accessible when writing to Firebase Storage. When reading you must use `resource` directly.